# How can I bulk publish 11,500 coupon codes in WooCommerce Smart Coupons?

Tags: woocommerce, coupon

We are running a deal with Groupon and have used Smart Coupons plugin with WooCommerce to import 11,500 Groupon codes. I now need to activate them (aka plublish.) However, currently in the WooCommerce interface you can only select and publish 20 coupon codes at once. This would take ~7.5 hours to publish all codes. Does anyone know of a way to easily activate all 11,500 codes at once?